# How to modify a function parameter at the same time new vars are created on a loop?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, parameters

This is the code without any attempt to add `var nn = 99` to the loop

```
//note that the 'i' is a parameter of the function
function myFunction(arr, i) {
  for (i = i ? i + 5 : 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //...
  }
}
```

When I try to add a new `var` it do things I don't want:

**Edit:** it seems this is wrong

<del>`for (var nn = 99, i = i ? i + 5 : 1; i < arr.length; i++)
//created a new 'i'`</del>

or

```
for (i = i ? i + 5 : 1, var nn = 99; i < arr.length; i++)
//doesn't work :(
```

I know it is exactly the same if I move it outside. But one of the things I hate most, is to not be able to understand what I meant when reading a old code after some months. Moving that line inside the loop will make me understand that line easier.

Comment: What does it do what you don't want?

Comment: @Bergi it creates a new `var i` (what I want is to work with the parameter of the function `i`

Comment: what exactly do you want this loop to do?

Comment: @MikeyG the loop itself, nothing. But I want to set a new `var nn` on the loop while modifying the `i` of the function parameter (without creating a new `var i`) and everything on the loop header

Comment: can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: @MikeyG that is the only code, I don't want the loop to do anything in particular (yet)

Comment: And this, class, is why you should comment tricksy code.  Or, even better, avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the function's parameter. As `i` is a primitive value (number), JavaScript will call-by-value, not by-reference.

And as you name your second argument "i", it will be available as a local variable from start on. Using the var keyword with "i" somewhere won't change anything.

Comment: "You can't modify the function's parameter" check this `function myFunction(i){var i=99;return arguments[0];}` will output 99. But this also solves my question, there is no harm because it won't create another `i`

Comment: Surely you can assign new values (by using the name or the arguments array), but you won't be able to assign to references. It sounded a bit as you wanted to pass i by reference...

Answer (score 0):

> ((i = i ? i + 5 : 1) * 0) + 99

This will always equal 99.  But that does not matter, since it is still unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

If your goal is to loop through an array from a designated start spot then you can do this.

```
for (; i<arr.length; i++) {}
```

If you can't guarantee that i is a number, then you will have to perform some sort of checking.

```
for (var index=(i?i:0); index < arr.length; index++) {}
```

Javascript will pass primitives by value, so you cannot modify the source value from inside this function.  You can return the modified value if want.

```
ivar = func(arr, ivar);
function func(arr, i){
    for (;i<arr.length; i++) {}
    return i;
}
```